# How to Setup OpenEdge 10.2B

Tags: openedge

Can someone explain how to setup OpenEdge version 10.2B on a Windows machine? I've searched about it but I couldn't find any resources. Hope that someone can explain it in a simple way.

Answer (score 0):

You might try starting at http://progress.com.  All of the documentation is online:

[OpenEdge 10.2B documentation](https://community.progress.com/community_groups/openedge_general/w/openedgegeneral/1329.openedge-product-documentation-overview.aspx)

and there is a "community" forum available for questions that are perhaps a bit more focused than "How to Setup?" https://community.progress.com

There is also http://progresstalk.com for more free-form discussion purposes.